# How to extend RepositoryDefinition annotation in spring data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

As we know, there is two ways to define a repository in Spring data. one is extending an interface (for example own `JpaRepository`)  and the second one is using RepositoryDefinition annotation. 
I've extended JpaRepository and created my own interface that repositories extend it. and with my own RepositoryFactoryBean, I can decide that what implementation should be inject as repositories in spring context. for example you can see this 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#d0e720

for example :

```
public interface DepartmentRepository extends SwiftRepository<DepartmentEntity,java.lang.Long> {

}
```

My question is how can I change this way to use annotation based repository definition?

For example something like this:

```
@MyOwmRepository(domainClass=DepartmentEntity.class,idClass=Long.class)
public interface DepartmentRepository {

}
```

Comment: Spring Data JPA API != JPA API. Tagging fixed!